# Angular Translate - Translating translate-values attr

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

Im having an issue while trying to use angular translate with some translate values that are dynamic and need first to be translated.

Here is a plunker with the issue better explained : [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/SWNgDOqUKt3M3jxEV3we?p=preview)

```html
<p translate="PARAGRAPH" translate-values="{username: ('userNameTranslate' | translate)}"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the html attribute in the parent translation

```
  PARAGRAPH: 'Hello <strong>{{username}}</strong> love!',
  userNameTranslate : 'User Name'
```

Then it works as you expect.

You have to add only dynamic content with translate parameter.
For example:

javascript file

```
var translations = {
  PARAGRAPH: 'Hello <strong>{{username}}</strong> and then some {{additionaldata}} love!',
};

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize', 'pascalprecht.translate']);

app.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider.translations('en', translations);
  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
  // Enable escaping of HTML
  $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escaped');
}]);

app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$translate', '$sce', function ($scope, $translate, $sce) {
  $scope.myUserName = 'my personal name';
  $scope.myAdditionalData = 'hello World';
}]);
```

and in the html file

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <p translate="PARAGRAPH" translate-values="{username:myUserName, additionaldata: myAdditionalData}"></p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer the thing is my userName may have some extra portion of content at the end which doesn't need to be completely bold.